# What does No such file or directory mean from lein test?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am having trouble understanding why I am getting the `(No such file or directory)` as shown in context below:

```
$ lein test

Testing rexfer.test.core
 (No such file or directory)

Ran 1 tests containing 1 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```

Here is my core.clj in the test directory:

```
(ns rexfer.test.core
  (:use [rexfer.core])
  (:use [clojure.test])
  (:require [util.core :as utl]))

(deftest gen-test-1
  (let [data-col-nams (first (utl/fetch-csv-data "columns.csv"))
        assess-rpt (utl/fetch-csv-data "")]
    (is (= 122 (count data-col-nams)))))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your test able to find "columns.csv"?

Comment: That's a good suggestion. I'll put columns.csv and the other file in by direct path. I though test looked at the top level project directory.

Comment: You should right this as an answer, because that got me to look at assess-rpt (utl/fetch-csv-data "")], which was causing the problem.

Comment: No need, just answer your own question and accept it :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, this was an error due to the following mapping. Once a value was added, the message went away.

`assess-rpt (utl/fetch-csv-data "")]`